# Execute multiple lines with python in one line for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a loop that appends to new list named `list1` and it is working, but how can I add something more like `print(x)` or anything useful to `list1.append(...)`?

```
word="abcdefg"
list1=[]
[list1.append(word[i]) for i in range(len(word))]
print(list1)
```

I've tried using `list1.append(word[i]);print("working")` and with `,`

Comment: List comprehension is not for executing for loop in single line, you are doing it totally wrong. You should read more about comprehensions

Comment: What exactly do you mean? What would be *"useful"*? What output were you *expecting?!* Why not just `print(list(word))`?

Comment: i sprecified that this is an example code (try and try)

Comment: But what does that *mean?* If you don't actually have a goal you're failing to reach, the question is unanswerable. If you're just experimenting, what about this has surprised you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define a function that does "more lines of code" and use it in the comprehension

```
word="abcdefg"
list1=[]
def add_and_print(character, container):
    container.append(character)
    print("adding", character)
[add_and_print(character, list1) for character in word]
```

comprehensions should be short and easy to read in the first place, avoid having a complex one, one condition one call and one for statement should be the maximum - if you need a complex looping etc, create a generator

```
[call(something) for something in some_container if something == foo]
```

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in comment, *List Comprehensions* are not *just* for executing `for` loop in single line. They are very powerful but you need to read about it. You may take a look at: [Python List Comprehensions: Explained Visually](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/).

However in your this particular case, all your code is doing is to convert the string to list, and printing it. You may do it in one line as:

```
>>> print(list("abcdefg"))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do -

```
list1 = [word[i] for i in range(len(word))]
```

or

```
list1 = [w for w in word]
```

Comment: So i can't add print to w -here- for w..?

Comment: Well, then Moinuddin's answer is better suited in this case